# I am looking for some examples of syntax trees

Tags: syntax-trees

Do you know of any good videos or sites with a variety of syntax trees. 
I am looking for examples to practice.
I found one or two videos on youtube but not as many as I expected.

Comment: you can make some here: http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/

Comment: Syntax trees vary greatly according to the framework of syntax being employed. They can be extremely complex, as in the GB/MP (Government and Binding / Minimalist Program) or quite simple, as in dependency grammars (DGs), or somewhere in between, as in TG (Transformational Grammar).

Comment: Is the motivation given for putting the question on hold intended as an answer to the question? :-)

Comment: Take a look at a book called "Beginning Syntax" by Linda Thomas.